# vs code settings.json using \\ instead of /

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I am using windows 10 and my vscode always generate path in settings.json with `\\` and this will I must edit manually to `/`. is there's a way how to change this parse if I config settings page via window and not `settings.json`?

Comment: Which setting is using this path style?

Comment: every time I put config to extension by window extention (not direct settings.json)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just write in settings window with `/` instead of `\`. e.x: `E:/Games/Half-Life/valve/addons/amxmodx/scripting/amxxpc.exe`